# Mod Rewrite Rules Confusion

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to do a few rules on my website, a few in particular

```
xxxx.com/administration/

xxxx.com/administration/users/

xxxx.com/administration/devices/ 

xxxx.com/administration/payments/
```

I'm trying to get it so on the administration page there is some text and links to the other 3 pages but any of the rules I try they just keep showing the same page even though the URL actually changes, so I assume the rules aren't being followed

I am currently trying the following - I have read up a bit on the rules but I will state here I am not an expert on them so please remember that.

```
RewriteRule administration/ administration.php
RewriteRule administration/users/ administrationusers.php
RewriteRule administration/devices/ administrationdevices.php
RewriteRule administration/payments/ administrationpayments.php
```

I have also tried the following sort of rule

```
RewriteRule administration/ adminfiles/administration.php
RewriteRule administration/(.*)/ adminfiles/$1.php
RewriteRule administration/(.*) adminfiles/$1.php
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic .htaccess file you should use.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^administration/?$          adminfiles/administration.php [L]
RewriteRule ^administration/([\w-]+)/?$     adminfiles/administration$1.php [L]
```

Note you website **must** be on the root folder (eg. for Wamp : wamp/www/).

If it's in a subfolder, use `RewriteBase /myfolder/` (eg. for Wamp : wamp/www/myfolder/)

Comment: That worked fantastically thank you :) Looking at yours and then at mine, I clearly have a lot to learn about these - I think I will spend a bit of time learning these before continuing.

Comment: You're welcome, remember to close this thread. You can find many informations here http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as